# Is there a way to code a Matlab script to review and segregate files into a new location?

Tags: matlab, directory

I have a script in matlab that will read data from a .xslx file and match information from patient files which are in separate folders. The idea is to make sure that items in the patient files are the same as our records(.xlsx file).

I have an "if loop" that will print 3 outputs. 1. If all the information matches, 2. If some of the information matches, 3. If none of the information matches.

You can find this section in the comments as " %match to MOSAIQ_EXCEL_FILE"

Is there a way I can create a copy or move files into segregated folders based on the results of the if loop. So all patient files on conditions 1,2, or 3 are then in new folders

```matlab
clear;clc
Mosaiq_missing=[];Mismatch_dose_plan=[];no_plan=[];false_dose=[];

% Reads Data from this file
% Several patient folders are in this location
dirpat='C:\Users\Desktop\dummy_pts\';
[patnamen,~]=getfil(dirpat);
% This contains the records I wish to match values with
%Mataches IDs from this file
dirloc='C:\Users\Desktop\ProjectK&S\Masterfile.xlsx';
MOSAIQ=readtable(dirloc);
% MOSAIQ.ida=cellstr(num2str(MOSAIQ.ida));
oma=MOSAIQ(ismember(MOSAIQ.ida, patnamen),:);

co=[2 2 2 2 2 2];dc=1;
for pp=1:length(patnamen)
    clearvars -except dirpat patnamen dc pp Mosaiq_missing Mismatch_dose_plan no_plan false_dose wrong_dose_dir repeat oma oma_namen
    mismatch=0; hl=0;
    patientname=patnamen{pp};

    if ismember(patientname,oma.ida)
        display(['loading patient: ',patientname])
        dirloc=[fullfile(dirpat,patientname),'\'];
        pa = genpath(dirloc);
        splitfil=regexp(pa,'\;','split')';

% read dose plan locations 
     DOSEplek=cellfun(@isempty,regexp(splitfil,'DOSE'))==0;
     PLANplek=cellfun(@isempty,regexp(splitfil,'PLAN'))==0; 
     DOSE=splitfil(DOSEplek);
     PLAN=splitfil(PLANplek);


     if sum(PLANplek)>0
        [RTplan_files,~]=getfil(PLAN{1});

        for pl=1:length(RTplan_files)
            info=dicominfo(fullfile(PLAN{1},RTplan_files{pl}));

            beam_name=cell(length(fieldnames(  info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence)),1);
            BeamMetersets=nan(length(fieldnames(  info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence)),1);


            for p=1:length(fieldnames(   info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence))
            BeamMetersets(p)=info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.(['Item_',num2str(p)]).BeamMeterset;
            beam_name(p)={info.BeamSequence.(['Item_',num2str(p)]).BeamDescription};
            end
            fraction_number=info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.NumberOfFractionsPlanned;


        end

        %match to MOSAIQ_EXCEL_FILE

                loc=ismember(oma.ida,patientname);%cellfun(@isempty,regexpi(oma_namen,patientnaam))==0;
                MOSAIQ_sel=table2cell(oma(loc,:));

                if size(MOSAIQ_sel,1)==size(BeamMetersets,1)
                    if sum(~ismember(BeamMetersets,cell2mat(MOSAIQ_sel(:,10))))==0
                        disp('x, right number of beam, Right Values Everything Matches!!')

                    else
                        disp('x, right number of beam -- wrong values!!!')
                        BeamMetersets;
                        mosaiq_beam_values=cell2mat(MOSAIQ_sel(:,10));

                    end

                else
                    disp('x there is an error!!! DO SOMETHING!!!')

                end





     end
    end
end
```

Some items were changed to protect information but I've gotten this script in its native form to work. I just don't know if how to (or if I can) do the automatic segregation part. Any ideas or advice?

Comment: You can pass a full path to file-writing routines, like you can to file-reading routines. Just dynamically change that path using e.g. `sprintf` to generate the desired path on the desired location.

Comment: you mean like `if a; path=['C:/A/' filename]; elseif b; path=['C:/B/' filename];` ? Just simply that

Comment: I tried your suggestion Ander adding path=['C:/A/'] under the if, and then both else conditions, but the folders seem empty.
```matlab
 if size(MOSAIQ_sel,1)==size(BeamMetersets,1)
                    if sum(~ismember(BeamMetersets,cell2mat(MOSAIQ_sel(:,10))))==0
                        disp('Keith, right number of beam, Right Values Everything Matches!!')
                        path=['C:\A\PerfectMatches'];
                
```